# React-native style to text elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native

I have defined JSX like this

```
<View style={[color: 'red']}>
<Text>Text1</Text>
<Text>Text2</Text>
<Text>Text3</Text>
</View>
```

View component doesn't have color property and it doesn't apply the text color settings of child  elements.

I don't want to apply same style on individual  elements.
How can I define the style on the parent and apply to all child elements like normal in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no simple way to inherit style from super Componnet.

Maybe you can custom a component like this:

```
 class YourComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    let children = [];
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (item, index) => {
      // textStyle is the style that you want children to inherit
      children.push(React.cloneElement(item, this.props.textStyle));
    });

    return (
      <View>
        { children }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The style is being propagated between `Text` components, so you could do something like:

```
<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
  <Text>Text1</Text>
  <Text>Text2</Text>
  <Text>Text3</Text>
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than applying a style to each element individually you could use something like the lodash `_.map` and render each child programatically and declare the style once.

Were you trying to do this because you wanted different colours on each of the text tags?

To make it less code you can "de-structure" it too.

```
const { aStyle, anotherStyle, andAnotherStyle } = styles;
```

Instead of the `styles.aStyle. styles.anotherStyle...`.